# Does the shell go through all the directories in PATH every time?

Tags: shell

If the shell is unable to find an executable in the directories mentioned in the PATH environment variable. Does it store this information somewhere to make the subsequent calls faster or it again searches all the directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many shells keep a record of commands which they *have* found on the `PATH`, so that they don’t need to explore all the `PATH` entries when a known command is invoked. You can see this *e.g.* on Bash or Zsh by running the

```
hash
```

command.

Some shells such as Tcsh might *only* consider this record of commands: by default Tcsh scans the path when it starts, and when the path is updated, and doesn’t look at the path again (in particular when a command isn’t found). This can be changed using the `autorehash` setting, and issuing the `rehash` command will also result in the path being scanned again.

However as far as I’m aware, no shell remembers commands which *have not* been found. This ensures that, in shells which scan the path when they encounter a missing command, missing commands can be directly added to a directory in the `PATH`, or have their directory added to the `PATH` variable, and be found the next time they are invoked, without telling the shell to scan for commands again.

Adding a new version of a command which already exists on the `PATH` requires manual intervention in more cases than adding a missing command, since the shell is liable to remember the version that already was available on the `PATH`; in such cases, `hash -r` or a targeted `hash -d` are required before the new version will be used.

Comment: I observed this after experimenting with this. Whenever we do source ~/.bashrc, the shell would remove the entries in the hash table. But suppose another shell process makes these changes, then the hash entries still exist. Does the shell automatically reloads the entries?

Comment: @satinder if the shell “knows” that a given command is found in a given directory, and some other process adds the command to another directory earlier in the `PATH`, the first shell won’t automatically reload, no; you’d need to run `hash -r` or `hash -d`.